# Angular2 : Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-steps'

Tags: angular

I have been trying to execute the following code:

states.component.html

```
<p-steps [model]="items"></p-steps>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { StepsModule, MenuItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-states',
  templateUrl: './states.component.html',
  styles: []
})
```

states.component.ts

```
export class StatesComponent implements OnInit {

  items: MenuItem[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {label: 'Step 1'},
            {label: 'Step 2'},
            {label: 'Step 3'}
        ];
  }

}
```

when connecting to the website I obtain the following results :

- Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-steps'.

Any idea ??

Comment: does `p-steps` component has `@Input() model` property?

Comment: p-steps does not have any @Input model property. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/steps

Answer (score 2):

I see you have imported the module into your component, but have you imported the PrimeNG `StepsModule` into your parent module?

```
import { StepsModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StepsModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you had it to your imports in your  xxxx.spec.ts file too?
I had the same issue with MenuBarModule.
I just added it to my component.spec.ts like this

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MenubarModule],
        declarations: [ HeadComponent]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes error is a little confusing, to investigate

remove `model`, and compile again,

- if error changed to can't find p-steps or something like that, it means that your module can't access p-steps, so you need to check if it's exported on it's own module(in `exports`), and also need to check if your module has imported the other module in `providers`
- if error is gone, it means p-steps doesn't have `model` input

Answer (score 0):

Add **import {PanelMenuModule} from 'primeng/panelmenu';** in app.module.ts and **PanelMenuModule** in imports block